# (Feel / send) (shivers / a shiver) down one's spine

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, expressions, phrases

According to the Cambridge Dictionary definition the phrase "[shiver down your spine](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/shiver-up-and-down-your-spine) means:

a frightened or excited feeling:

- At its most terrifying, his writing **sends shivers down my spine**.

But the problem is that when the idiom's construction changes as follows:

- Whenever I hear that music, **I feel "a" shiver down my spine.**

I was wondering if there are two different idioms structurally when it comes to the verbs "send" and "feel":

> - **Send shivers** down one's spine

And

> - **Feel a shiver** down one's spine

or the construction:

> - **feel shivers** down one's spine

is correct too?

Please let me know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples are all fine. The expression works in many arrangements. At [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/shiver) you will find 22 examples of both 'shiver' and 'shivers' used in a variety of constructions. (Look for **shiver<sup>1</sup>** then **NOUN**. You need the *first* definition. Then open "*more example sentences*".)

It may also be helpful to look at the the next definition (1.1 - **the shivers**), if only to differentiate between them.